# How can I restrict a bash find to only specific sub-sub-directories

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, find

I'm trying to list all the files in a specific sub-directory but different directories which are themselves on a different volume.

The following works, but only on a fully specific sub-directory (and I've got hundreds of them):
`find "/Volumes/Products/Specific Product Directory/Work Instructions" -print`

What I haven't been able to figure out is how to search across varied sub-directories.  So, for example, using the wild character * in place of each specific product directory:
`find "/Volumes/Products/*/Work Instructions" -print` // Does *not* work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` is only interpreted by the shell when not quoted.

```
find "/Volumes/Products/"*"/Work Instructions" -print
find /Volumes/Products/*/Work\ Instructions -print
```